# Не могу перевести stdClass Object в array

Tags: php

Дано:

```
$array = 'Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [did] => 123
        [owner_id] => 123123
        [title] => By
        [size] => 2061840
        [ext] => gif
        [url] => http://vk.com/
        [thumb] => http://cs610521.vk.me
        [thumb_s] => http://cs610521.vk
    )

)';
```

Нужно перевести это чудо в обычный массив. Ничего не получается. Пробовал так, ничего не выходит:

```
print_r($array[0]->did);
```

Comment: Вы строку пытаетесь в массив перевести? О_о

Comment: @VasyOk, я пытаюсь перевести объект в массив

Comment: $array = (array)$array;

Comment: @ArchDemon то же самое выводит

Comment: господи, откуда вы это получаете?

Comment: @Etki, API vk

Comment: @Rammsteinik нет, vk отдает вполне себе валидный json

Comment: По делу ничего нет

Comment: @Rammsteinik, потому что вы где-то делаете `print_r($x, true)`, и всякий человек в своем уме вместо парсинга вот этого вот будет раскапывать, где же вы его сделали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этой строке Вы объявляете СТРОКУ:

```
$array = 'Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [did] => 123
        [owner_id] => 123123
        [title] => By
        [size] => 2061840
        [ext] => gif
        [url] => http://vk.com/
        [thumb] => http://cs610521.vk.me
        [thumb_s] => http://cs610521.vk
    )

)';
```

Хотите объект, делайте что-то типа этого:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->did = 123;
$obj->title = 'asd';
```

Хотите, чтобы он был в массиве -

```
$array = [$obj, $obj1, $obj2];
```

тогда и

```
print_r($array[0]->did);
```

будет работать.

**upd**

Вы утверждаете что работаете с vk api, так вот, он отдает валидный json\xml.
Пример работы с json

```
$array = json_decode($apiResponse); // $apiResponse - ответ сервера вк в формате json
$array[0]->did // именно то, что вы хотели получить!
```

А если Вы сделаете

```
var_dump ($array);
```

ps изучите документацию. [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php) [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php)

То получите именно ту самую строку из вопроса.

Comment: касаемо данного $array задумок нет?

Comment: @Rammsteinik в стопятидесятый раз - поправьте то место, откуда вы его берете, и для вас наступит счастье.

Comment: Тот $array, что Вы привели - результат работы var_dump (или print_r) и это строка. Если сделать:

    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->did = 123;
    $obj->title = 'asd';
    $array = [$obj];
    var_dump ($array);

Вы получите именно такую строку, которая НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ php кодом.
Да, Вы можете её распарсить её и создать массив объектов, но это дичайший велосипед с костылями вместо колес.

upd. дополнил ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
$data  = '[{"xx":"1"}]';  
$array = json_decode($data,true);  
print_r($array);
```

result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [xx] => 1
        )

)
```